# GridView Edit - Check Row Color

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm wondering if it's possible to check a  GridViewRow's BackColor during the GridView_OnRowEditing event.

My current code only returns [Name=0, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)] when I try to get the row.BackColor

Here is my code:

```
    protected void GridView_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = GridView1.SelectedRowStyle;
        if (row.BackColor == Color.White)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "ERROR - cannot edit this row";
        }
        else
        {
            //Different code
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Is there an alternative to DataGridViewRow.Tag with asp GridViewRow?

Comment: Why check the color of a row? And if you check the `TAG` property instead? In the TAG property you can put any object, like a `Boolean` and check them before editing.

Comment: @RichardDias I'm currently highlighting rows that have been 'scanned in' so if a row is green or red, then it can be edited. If the row is white, then it cannot be touched until it has been scanned in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find my own solution by doing this:

```
if (GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].BackColor != Color.SeaGreen &&
                GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].BackColor != Color.IndianRed)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            errorLabel.Text = "Please scan roll before updating QtyRun";
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }
```

@RichardDias idea would've been an okay, but **asp GridViewRow** *does not* *allow* for the Tag property (**DataGridViewRow** *does allow* for the Tag property).

Another reason I would not have used his method is because I'm already taking time to highlight specific rows (which needs to be done, no alternative) in my gridview. To add another method of 'confirmation' seems inefficient.

By using my method, I was able to utilize my initial 'confirmation by row color' method to cancel the Editing event. Regardless, thank you @RichardDias for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try do something like this:

```
public void ScanRows()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
       row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
       //Indicate that this row already was scanned
       row.Tag = true;
    }
}

protected void GridView_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    var row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    if (!((bool)(row.Tag ?? false)))
    {
       errorLabel.Text = "ERROR - cannot edit this row";
    }
    else
    {
        //Different code
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh I see. I'm going to try this out tomorrow. I'll mark you right once I get it working. thank you.

Comment: hey just to let you know, asp GridView's do not have Tag has a property. DataGridView does but I'm using an asp GridView.